# How to get from an user a value input in minutes with Kotlin in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, get, numbers

I´m a really beginner in android developing with Kotlin.

I have an application which needs to get time as an input from the user, it´s getting in milleseconds rn but I think it´s not really friendly for the user so I´d like to get it in minutes.

Please find the code below:

build

```
package com.ix.ibrahim7.recipesapp.model

import android.os.Parcelable
import android.renderscript.Int2
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Step(
    var id:String,
    var title:String,
    var description:String,
    var duration: Double
):Parcelable{
    constructor():this(id:"",title:"",description:"",duration:0.0)
}
```

screen

```
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/etxt_step_duration"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Duração (em seg)"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:lines="4"
                android:maxLines="4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimeUnit`

Try doing something like this:

```
val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliseconds)
```

Also you can perform the calculation manually:

```
val minutes = milliseconds / 1000 / 60
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user fills in the `EditText` minutes, then:

```
val minutes = etxt_step_duration.text.toString().toLongOrNull() ?: 0L
val milliseconds = minutes * 60 * 1000

Step(duration = milliseconds.toDouble())
```